# How to pass array multiple array key and value from Controllers to Views in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
//declare array variable
$data['direct_sponsor_bonus_vals']=array('package_size'=>'');

// insert element to array
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $data['direct_sponsor_bonus_vals']=array('package_size'=>$x);
}

//show output
foreach($direct_sponsor_bonus_vals As $key => $value )
{
    echo $value . ","; 
}
```

Output :

```
10,
```

How to make Output become like below :

```
0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

I have tried replace

```
$data['direct_sponsor_bonus_vals']=array('package_size'=>$x);
```

by

```
$data['direct_sponsor_bonus_vals']['package_size'][] = $x;
```

but still not working.

Update :
I think the bug is at foreach loop. Need 2 of foreach loop. I tried:

```
foreach ($direct_sponsor_bonus_vals As $key => $value ) 
{
    foreach ($value As $key_inner => $value_inner)
    {
        echo $value_inner;   // whatever
    }
}
```

Still has bug error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't actually understand which part of your code meant for a view but I think this is what you are looking for

**In a Controller**

```
$array = null;

for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
    $array[]= array('package_size'=>$x);
}
```

//to send above array to view just do `$data['direct_sponsor_bonus_vals'] = $array;`

**in a view**

```
foreach($direct_sponsor_bonus_vals as $value)
{
    echo $value['package_size'] . ","; 
}
```